# To Parse values from XML to Selenium webdriver by using Python

Tags: xml, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Suppose I need to pass username and Password from Xml file . How can i parse those values to the proper element fields by using python .

Answer (score 0):

Without any information, all I can tell you is you can use the `lxml` library to import your xml file, then you can use the library to parse the file, assign your username and password to variables, then use those variables when running selenium to `.send_keys()` to the form fields.